# Could not get pipeline InitializeMongoDbCollectionIndexes(domain)

Tags: upgrade

I have recently upgraded web site from Sitecore 8.2 to 8.2 update 7.
I have enabled the sitecore xDB in sitecore.xDB.config.
Now when i am browsing the web site, i am getting the following error.

Could not get pipeline InitializeMongoDbCollectionIndexes(domain:)

[image]

I have already tried issue [Cannot patch Sitecore initialize pipeline (Sitecore 8.1 Update 3)](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1894/cannot-patch-sitecore-initialize-pipeline-sitecore-8-1-update-3) but it does solve in my case.

Comment: Are you getting this issue in dev, test or production environment? 

initializeMongoDbCollectionsIndexes is a new pipeline added in SC8.2 update 7 (link for release notes: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update7/Release%20Notes) 

Can you check your configuration to see that it is pointing to the right pipeline and check that you're solution is building/deploying against the right version of Sitecore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered similar error when i upgraded to update 7 and enabled xDB in configuration.
Please make sure you have the following configuration in pipelines section of  Sitecore.Analytics.Mongodb.config(in app_config/include).

```
<initializeMongoDbCollectionsIndexes>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeMongoDbCollectionsIndexes.EnsureMongoDbCollectionsIndexesProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDb" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.InitializeMongoDbCollectionsIndexes.EnsureMongoDbInteractionCollectionIndexForGetAllHistoricalInteractionsProcessor, Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDb" />
  </initializeMongoDbCollectionsIndexes>
```